# Calculating x position using .css('left')

Tags: jquery, css

I have a issue finding the center of the screen. I have jQuery code:

```
arr[i].css('left')=='560px';
```

which will animate the html `obj(arr[i])` when it's in the center of the screen.

I have posted my sample, if you can have a look at this link: http://kashi.9f.com/Carousel/index.html

On hitting the left and right key the objects starts moving onto the respective sides. My objective is to highlight the 'letter' which is at center of the screen. Some times when I hit left/right key, the html obj at '560px' don't always animate. It will be either the next or the previous item other than item at '560px' which gets animated.

Please can anybody help me how I can make this work so that only the center obj animates.

If you need, you can take a look at the js (script.js) and css (style.css) file which is in the same directory as that of html.

Comment: Please post relevant code here.

Comment: @Walk you don't have to comment on the question, the OP get notification for any new answer and any comment on the answer, please comment on your own answer after editing it.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. Wasn't sure what to do there because I initially though he was using the assignment operator wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're checking the element's coordinates left position before jQuery has finished moving it. Add your function as a callback to animate.

http://api.jquery.com/animate/